# How to copy and paste multiple values in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have two files: the first containing the list of columns, and the second with script which I need to paste values from the second list

**LIST 1**

```
COLUMN1
COL2
COLUMN3_VERYLONGNAME
```

**LIST 2**

```
ALTER TABLE T.TABLE1 ALTER COLUMN
ALTER TABLE T.TAB2 ALTER COLUMN
ALTER TABLE T.TABLELONGNAME ALTER COLUMN
```

I know I can use regular expressions to add the same value to each line, but what if I have list with multiple values to append?

The result should look like:

**RESULT LIST**

```
ALTER TABLE T.TABLE1 ALTER COLUMN COLUMN1
ALTER TABLE T.TAB2 ALTER COLUMN COL2
ALTER TABLE T.TABLELONGNAME ALTER COLUMN COLUMN3_VERYLONGNAME
```

Note that all lists have various line length.

Comment: You'd better write a script in your favorite scripting language.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge 2 text files into one, same lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24403885/merge-2-text-files-into-one-same-lines)