# Cut and Paste to Specific Column Line in Notepad ++

Tags: notepad++

I have a text file that has two "columns". I need the text below to coincide with these "columns" but currently I have to manually cut and paste all every individual text so that it matches the column line, or hit space/tab until they match. In my case, it is column 117. So for example it looks like this:

```
Client            Contact

Client A       ContactA
Client B Contact B
Client C          Contact C
```

And I need it to look like this:

```
Client           Contact
Client A         Contact A
Client B         Contact B
Client C         Contact C
```

Is there a shortcut or way that I could select a text and tell notepad++ to paste it beginning in column 117?

Thanks

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24404352/546871) answer your question?

Comment: @AdrianHHH unfortunately no, the things im trying to cut and paste are in the same file. All of the text I need to paste is before column line 117, and i need to paste it all to column line 117, but they are in different column lines (for example one starts in line 110, others in 80, etc.) But thanks anyway

Comment: Do you have special characters between the columns such as tabs? Is column 1 "Client" always of the same length or of different length?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to explain how to separate column 1 from column 2 on each line. What character(s) separate the columns? Or, what denotes the start of column 2?