# Merge 2 files in Notepad++ or Vim

Tags: linux, file, vim, notepad++, vi

I have 2 files with me.

- `File1.txt`:

  ```
  Bus
  Railway
  Cinema
  Motor
  ```
- `File2.txt`:

  ```
  Stand
  Station
  Theatre
  Cycle
  ```

Above 2 files I have with me and I need output like below.

- `Output.txt`:

  ```
  Bus Stand
  Railway Station
  Cinema Theatre
  Motor Cycle
  ```

I have thousands of lines like this and I can't do this one by one manually. Someone please help me to automate this.

I have Notepad++ and Vim ( i can't Install any other apps, because it's Office System )

Comment: Formatting is important. Because you didn't bother formatting your question properly the first person to answer your question wasted their time writing an incorrect answer. Put in more effort next time.

Comment: My advice is to use command [paste](https://linux.die.net/man/1/paste) from Linux: `paste -d' ' File1.txt File2.txt >Output.txt` (`-d' '` means "join lines with spaces instead of tabs").

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge 2 text files into one, same lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24403885/merge-2-text-files-into-one-same-lines)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `vim` macros. First, get your file into the following state:

```
Bus Railway Cinema Motor
Stand Station Theatre Cycle
```

Then, with your cursor on the first line (in normal mode) do the following key combo

```
qq0f<Space>r<Enter>jf<Space>r<Enter>2kddp@qq
```

Where `<Space>` is an actual space, and `<Enter>` is an actual enter key.
You have now recorded a recursive `vim` macro. Your file should look like this

```
Bus
Stand
Railway Cinema Motor
Station Theatre Cycle
```

With your cursor on the third line, after which, you hit `@q`, giving you

```
Bus
Stand
Railway
Station
Cinema
Theatre
Motor
Cycle
```

Then do `vipJ` to join all lines in the paragraph.

#### Edit 1

Upon seeing the revised question, I propose the following:
Use the command line. Others have pointed out the use of a few unix utilities that can make the job easy.

If that is beyond the constraints of your machine, you can do the following in `vim`:

First, get your `output.txt` into this format:

```
Bus
Railway
Cinema
Motor

Stand
Station
Theatre
Cycle
```

Then record the following macro to use on subsequent output files.

```
qqgg}j<Ctrl>vGI<Space><Esc>gg<Ctrl>v}k$xdiph"0P:%s/\s\+/<Space>/g
```

Which should solve your first instance.
Then for your next instance, simply get the file into the format as previously shown and do `@q` to call the macro.

#### NOTE: The above only works when the entire file only contains two paragraphs to be merged.

A full explanation might be cumbersome and may ultimately be inaccurate, please use vim's inbuilt help texts to get it straight from the horse's mouth.

With regards to the files and how to do it a thousand times, I believe it is best to raise another question with your constraints as well as the file formats present, and the output required.

Comment: the question was poorly formatted so it sent you on the wrong path. You should probably read it again and adjust your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Opening the files:

```
vim -o file1.txt file2.txt
```

Jump to the second one by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>ww</kbd>, now copy the whole file:

```
:%y
```

Jump back to the first one <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>ww</kbd>, now we are going to make the yank register `0` blockwise:

```
:call setreg('0',getreg('0'), 'b')
```

Start insert adding five or more spaces then <kbd>Esc</kbd> and finally

```
"0p
:%s/\s\+/ /g
```

### Another vimish solution:

Open the files:

```
 vim -o file1.txt file2.txt
```

copy this function to the clipboard

```
function! Join_files()
    wincmd j
    %y
    wincmd k
    call setreg('0', getreg('0'), 'b')
    normal gg
    .s/$/     /
    normal $"0p
    %s/\s\+/ /g
endfunction
```

The next command loads the function to the vim memory

```
:@+
```

Now run the function

```
:call Join_files()
```

#### Explaining the function:

```
wincmd j .............................. jump to the other file
%y .................................... copy its content
wincmd k .............................. jump back
call setreg('0', getreg('0'), 'b') .... make yank register blockwise
normal gg .............................. jump to the line 1
.s/$/     / ............................ add five spaces
normal $"0p ............................ jump to end of line and paste yank register
%s/\s\+/ /g ............................. remove two or more spaces
```